# Trying to call an function with a variable imbedded in the middle of it in Python

Tags: python

I'm creating a program with a menu that asks the user via `raw_input` to choose a specific chapter of narrative in the program they want to read. That portion of the code is:

```
mainma = raw_input ("Which chapter do you want? (1-10): ")
```

Here's where my problem is: I'm trying to code the call so that it will go to the requested chapter that is defined as:

```
Chap(mainma)menu()
```

as I was working on the assumption that if `mainma = 1`, it would invoke `Chap1menu()` where that particular chapter data is stored, the same if `mainma = 3` it would invoke `Chap3menu()`. The syntax error I'm getting disagrees with me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You don't really want to try to turn user input directly into variable names; it's possible but it's messy, brittle, and insecure. What you want to do instead is create a list or dictionary that maps the input to the chapter functions; something like:

```
chapters = {'1': Chap1Menu,
            '2': Chap2Menu,
            #etc.
           }
```

and then use it like so:

```
chapters[mainma]()
```

Comment: I think this is what I wanted to see happen. Thank you.

Comment: @Aaron , do you really do such different things for each chapter menu that they're different functions?

Answer (score 0):

You have an opportunity for efficient code design here -- presumably the chapter menu functions share a lot of behavior between them. You shouldn't every copy-and-paste code in a program like that, because it's harder to read and a risk to update (too easy to get them out of whack with each other).

Whatever you were putting into Chapter#Menu, write a sliiiightly more general function that accepts the chapter number as an argument. This helps reuse code that's similar between chapters. The differences get stored in some list or dictionary (here `insides`, minimal):

```
insides = list('qwertywuiop')

def ChapterMenus(chapternum, **kwargs):
    print('Chapter %d: About the Letter %s'%(chapternum, insides[chapternum]))
    print(kwargs)


if __name__=='__main__':
    mainma = raw_input("Which chapter do you want? (1-10): ")
    mainma = int(mainma) #Be more helpful validating this
    if mainma in range(1,11):
        ChapterMenus(mainma, text='Ants')
    else:
        print('Tsk! A real chapter number, please!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `m` as a parameter to the function `Chapmenu`. For example:

```
def Chapmenu(m):
    if m == 1:
        # code for Chap1menu goes here
    elif m == 2:
        # code for Chap2menu goes here
    elif m == 3:
        # code for Chap3menu goes here
```

etc.

Then just call `Chapmenu(mainma)`